# mypy unreachable on Guard Clause

Tags: python, mypy

I have a problem where when I try to check if the given value's type is not what I expect I'll log it and raise an error.

However, `mypy` is complaining. What I'm doing wrong?

Simplified example:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union
from logging import getLogger


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: Union[float, int]) -> None:
        self.logger = getLogger("dummy")
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other: Union[MyClass, float, int]) -> MyClass:
        if not isinstance(other, (MyClass, float, int)):
            self.logger.error("Other must be either MyClass, float or int") # error: Statement is unreachable  [unreachable]
            raise NotImplementedError

        return self.add(other)

    def add(self, other: Union[MyClass, float, int]) -> MyClass:
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return MyClass(self.value + other.value)

        return MyClass(self.value + other)
```

Please notice it does not complain when I run it on [mypy-play.net](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=9945c3de7d01e9b2428a1f4dd0832739) but locally it raises:

```
main.py:13: error: Statement is unreachable  [unreachable]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: You need to [turn the `--warn-unreachable` option on](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=9945c3de7d01e9b2428a1f4dd0832739&flags=warn-unreachable). Either remove that guard, turn off the flag or use `# type: ignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mypy is complaining because due to the input you set `Union[MyClass, float, int]` and your condition `if not isinstance(other, (MyClass, float, int)):`, if the arguments follows the given types, the code will never be reached.

Mypy expect that everybody using your code will sent correct argument types (that's why you add types). You can disable this warning either with a `type: ignore[unreachable]` or just by unsettling the option in local.

For the `mypy-playground`, you have to activate the option [image: Option to activate --warn unreachable]

Comment: So can you please let me know which one I should do? 1) Do not check the type since I type-checked the argument. 2) ignore[unreachable].

Comment: I think you should keep checking the type. Having typing won't block a user to call your function with a bad type.
Depending on your usage in your codebase, you can either globally disable the `unreachable` or just there locally. IHMO, I prefer to do it locally.